# Random HTML Email characters replaced with "=" in Outlook

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, outlook, html-email

I've stripped this email down and it's still displaying the problem: certain random characters are being replaced by "=" in Outlook. I'm using PHP/Codeigniter and sparkpost.com as the mailing mechanism.

In outlook.com:

[image: Outlook.com screenshot]

In gmail/other clients tested, it's fine

Email Config:

```
$config['protocol']  = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host'] = "smtp.sparkpostmail.com";
$config['smtp_user'] = "SMTP_Injection";
$config['smtp_pass'] = " ";
$config['smtp_port'] = 587;
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
$config['mailtype']  = 'html';
$config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
$config['newline'] = "\r\n";
```

Stripped down HTML for Email

https://pastebin.com/inBrhEtJ

Any ideas?

Comment: Check this link it will help http://group-mail.com/html-email/tips-to-create-html-email-that-works-with-all-email-clients-part-1/

Comment: try quoted printable as the encoding as well see if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your config add the following line:

```
$config['crlf'] = "\r\n";
```

The reason is the following:

According to [RFC 2045](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2045.txt) for a quoted-printable encoding `\r\n` must be used.
However Codeigniter breaks this rule because they say some server can't handle this properly, and use therefore `\n` only.

This is documented in the E-Mail Library under /system/libraries/EMail.php.
You can see that [in Line 182](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/libraries/Email.php#L182) on the official Github Rep.